# Continuity of Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I am going over a statement in Rudin which says "Suppose $f$ is  a real differentiable function on $[a,b]$ and suppose $f^{'}(a)<k<f^{'}(b)$. Then there is a point $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f^{'}(x)=k$.

This theorem is very similar to Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions. But note that here that the continuity of $f^{'}(x)$ has not been assumed. This is where my confusion lies. Unless we are sure that  $f^{'}(x)$ is continuous, how can we apply Intermediate Value Theorem to  $f^{'}(x)$? Obviously, the statement must be correct, but can someone provide me with the intuition on this?

Comment: We can't apply it (yet). It is proved [there] that derivatives have the intermediate value property, even if they are not continuous.

Comment: @Daniel: Another intuition is that if derivative exists, then the left hand and right hand derivatives do exist. Derivative is nothing but existence of limit of quotient function. So, both left hand and right hand limit of quotient function exist if derivative exists. Hence $f^{'}(x)$ is continuous and hence Intermediate Value Theorem can be applied to $f^{'}(x)$. I may have missed out on proof of this in Rudin. Can you suggest where it is?

Comment: In general, derivatives aren't continuous. But they nevertheless have the intermediate value property.

Comment: Can you suggest me the proof of this? Its non-intuitive in some sense

Comment: That's theorem 5.12 of Rudin's PMA. The proof is right there.

Comment: Ok so in a  more general context, what is the graphical intuition of the fact that a non-continuous function (in this case the derivative function) attains all intermediate values in some bound?

Comment: For discontinuous derivatives, graphical intuition is left behind. As long as the discontinuities of a derivative are isolated, you can get somewhere by saying that it oscillates near the discontinuity. If things get wilder, getting a mental picture is beyond most humans.